# Two records are inserted in database when the synchronized method is called from different system/browser simultaneously

Tags: javascript, java, synchronization, hql, data-synchronization

I have one method that will insert student attendance record in database. There should be only one attendance record for a student in database for a date. I have to make sure data consistency. I have defined this method as a synchronization method.(ie, Two records should not be inserted for a particular student if we try simultaneously from different system/browser).

```
 public synchronized void SaveOrupdateAttendance(final StudentAttendance studentAttendance) throws ApplicationException {
    /*Method Code*/
  saveOrUpdate(studentAttendance);
}
```

Two records are inserted in db. What is wrong with my approach. Please help

Comment: Your method is probably being called twice.  We would need to see more code.

Comment: @SteveSmith Yeah. It is calling from a loop from another synchronized method . In that case also it should work fine. Ryt?

Comment: Synchronization is not magic. For it to work, you should make sure that there is only one instance of the class where it is defined. A [mcve] would be best, as the amount of code you are given is insufficient to pinpoint your problem.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Hi, i have defined only one object of the class where my synchronized method has been defined. which in turn calls another synchronized method in the same class in a loop.

Comment: Synchronization only prevents a method being run concurrently by two or more threads.  It doesn't prevent methods being called multiple times.  As has been said, we'd need to see more code.

Answer (score 1):

synchronisation in JAVA only handle the multi threads to share the resource one by one. It doest mean that the data you use inside the method should not be duplicate .

Have a check before you insert the data into the database or design the application to not allow multiple submission